# VBA to look up a string in a cell based on font size and add text to it

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA code that will search for a string that might appear multiple times in a spreadsheet but in different font sizes.

-First look up the string based on specific font size (ex: "AABBCCC123", font 11)

-Second add text to the end of the string (B222)

The idea is to create a unique ID

Thanks

Comment: you'll improve you chances of getting help if you try something on your own first and/or show what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim myFontSize As Long
Dim myText As String
Dim myRange, myCell As Range

Set myRange = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:A10")    'define your lookup Range
myFontSize = 11                                     'define your lookup Font size
myText = "AABBCCC123"                               'define your lookup text

For Each myCell In myRange                                          ' check all cells in your Range
    If myCell.Font.Size = myFontSize And myCell.Text = myText Then  ' look for your font size and text
        myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "B222" & myCell.Text            ' update a cell to the right by adding B222 before your text
        'myCell.Value = "B222" & myCell.Text                        ' update your cell by adding B222 before your text
    End If
Next
End Sub
```